# different usage of the word "only"

Tags: meaning, word-order, adverbs

What is the difference between the following sentences? Basically, I would like to understand how the meaning changes with the usage of *only* in each of them.

1. He ***only*** speaks English.
2. He speaks ***only*** English.
3. He speaks English ***only***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Only the trees were somewhat damaged
>   by last year's storm.

**Meaning:** Nothing except the trees was somewhat damaged by last year's storm.

> The only trees were somewhat damaged by last year's storm.

**Meaning:** The few trees which existed were somewhat damaged by last year's storm.

> The trees were only somewhat damaged by last year's storm.

**Meaning:** The trees were not completely damaged by last year's storm.

> The trees were somewhat damaged only by last year's storm.

**Meaning:** The trees were somewhat damaged by nothing except last year's storm.

> The trees were somewhat damaged by last year's only storm.

**Meaning:** The trees were somewhat damaged by the one storm which occurred last year.

[Source](http://www.fortunecity.com/bally/durrus/153/gramch20.html#7)

Comment: Just on a point of site style: it would be more consistent to put the example sentences as quotes, and your explanation as regular text.

Comment: I'm not quite convinced by the second example; I've never seen only used to refer to more than one thing in that way. Perhaps 'the only tree was...'?

Comment: The second example is incorrect. For the given meaning, you'd have to say something like, "The only existing trees..." or "The only trees in that area...".

Comment: @Steve: I reformat the answer. Thank for reminding.

Comment: Very descriptive answer! A stupid question: does the same logic apply to any other adverbs (obviously, apparently, solely etc)?

Answer (score 3):

To the point, your sentences 2 and 3 actually have exactly the same meaning. Although the scope of the quantifier "only" usually changes based on what *follows* it in the sentence, in the exceptional usage of sentence 3 it is modifying only the *preceding* word, "English".

**He speaks only English**. == **He speaks English only**.

Answer (score 1):

> He **only** speaks English.

He does not read or write it. However, a listener may take this to mean the same as the next sentence.

> He speaks **only** English.

He does not speak any other languages.

> He speaks English **only**.

Same as above.